# PayPal "partner-payer-id" and "partner_client_id"

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-marketplaces

I am working on PayPal Marketplace API. On the Onboarding Integration Guide, I see this code for `requested_capabilities` param

```
"requested_capabilities": [{
  "capability": "API_INTEGRATION",
  "api_integration_preference": {
    "partner_id": "partner-payer-id",
    "rest_api_integration": {
      "integration_method": "PAYPAL",
      "integration_type": "THIRD_PARTY"
    },
    "rest_third_party_details": {
      "partner_client_id": partner_client_id,
      "feature_list": [
        "PAYMENT",
        "REFUND"
      ]
    }
  }
}]
```

My question is, where do I get the `partner-payer-id` and `partner_client_id`? Is these something I get from MY sandbox/live account or its from seller's (whos onboarding) account?

In either case, please help me to get those values.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Those values need to be provided by Paypal (either on Sandbox or Live env.)